# How to get the exact touch position of a image?

Tags: java, android, coordinates

I have an idea for implementing of a login with password as the image touch positions when the member touch the same position I have to login the user.Can anyone help me how to implement it I can get the position of screen only. and the x and y coordinated are changing even when I touch the same position.

Comment: call `ImageView#getImageMatrix()` and use one of Matrix "mapping" functions to map between screen/view <-> image points

Answer (score 0):

I would say create a custom View that extends **ImageView**:

```
public class PasswordView extends ImageView {

    public PasswordView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Any additional PasswordView setup
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float xTouchPos = event.getX();
        float yTouchPos = event.getY();

        // If the PasswordView was clicked
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            // Check if they touched in the secret spot

        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

By subclassing **ImageView**, you will still have access to all the standard features of an ImageView (setting an image source, etc.) and you will also be able to add the additional functionality for checking a user's touch position.

---

[Here's an example project](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/05/custom-view-with-user-interaction.html) that uses `onTouchEvent`.

Comment: Since im new to android can u pls refer some example or any referral links..it would be helpful for me..

Comment: Sure thing, I added an example to the answer.